# What to use to begin an email with if I don't know the name of the person reading

Tags: greetings, email

I want to write a letter to a company. Unfortunately I don't know the name of person who is responsible to respond to the email. In such a situation, I used to open my letter with "Dear Sir/Madam". Is there any better greeting to open emails with?

Comment: What kind of letter (nature? purpose?) I think "To whom it may concern" will work (in general). Also, I think it is okay to use what you mentioned: "Dear Sir/Madam", but kindly note that some people don't appreciate it when they are not 'named' (but that's another story)

Comment: A *letter* is a *paper* communication sent through the postal system. Many people are habitually much more informal in *emails* than they would be with letters (they'll use **Hello** or **Hi** as a salutation, for example). Arguably if your letter is sufficiently important to ask about it here, it's important enough for you to *find out the name of the recipient first*. But any suggestions here are all just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

1. > Esteemed *CompanyName*
2. > To whom it may concern

which keep a formal level.

If you know the position of the person you're talking to

> Dear *Position*

as in

> Dear CEO / Dear Manager

which are a bit more colloquial than the previous ones.